# Are events lost in jQuery when you remove() an element and append() it elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

What happens in jQuery when you `remove()` an element and `append()` it elsewhere?

It appears that the events are unhooked - as if you were just inserting fresh html (which I guess is what happening). But its also possible my code has a bug in it - so I just wanted to verify this behavior before I continue.

If this is the case - are there any easy ways to rehookup the events to just that portion of HTML, or a different way to move the element without losing the event in the first place.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, jQuery's approach with `remove()` is to unbind everything bound with jQuery's own `bind` (to prevent memory leaks).

However, if you just want to move something in the DOM, you don't have to `remove()` it first. Just `append` to your heart's content, the event bindings *will* stick around :)

For example, paste this into your firebug on this page:

```
$('li.wmd-button:eq(2)').click(function(){ alert('still here!') }).appendTo(document.body)
```

And now scroll down to the bottom of this page and click on the little globy icon now buried under the SO footer. You will get the `alert`. All because I took care to not `remove` it first.

Comment: cool. i was hoping something like that was the case. yay for interactive stackoverflow !

Comment: @ceescentfresh happy ten year anniversary of answering this :-)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: holy crap ten years

Comment: Perfecto !!!! :)

Answer (score 55):

The jQuery *detach()* function is the same as *remove()* but preserves the event handlers in the object that it returns. If you have to remove the item and place it somewhere else with everything you can just use this.

```
var objectWithEvents = $('#old').detach();
$('#new').append(objectWithEvents);
```

Check the API docs here: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: I needed to sort a bunch of elements remove them from their parent using $parent.empty(), then append the sorted list of elements back on their parent. THIS was the correct answer for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery1.3.1 live() to bind events and you won't need to worry about this..

Update: live events are deprecated now, but you can get the same effect from $(document).on().

Comment: so yes to my original question? what exactly happens. i'll check into 'live' now

Comment: definitely good to know about live - but got to be careful of the caveats here http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn

Comment: not applicable if you're working with specific dom objects and not selectors.  this was my first idea, too.