# Swapping div contents with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swap

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="large">
    <img src="/images/photos/Interior.jpg" alt="The interior" style="[...]" />
    <div class="caption">The interior</div>
</div>
<div class="small">
    <img src="/images/photos/Bedroom.jpg" alt="Bedroom" style="[A different ...]" />
    <div class="caption">A bedroom</div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking a `div.small`, I'd like both the images and captions to swap container divs. The catch is I can't just swap the src, as there are a bunch of inline styles set which need to be preserved. Finally, once the images have been swapped, I want to apply my custom function `.fitToParent()` to both of them.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Lol rofl etc. !! I just found myself looking for a good way to swap div contents using jQuery. And look who answered this question.....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.small').click(function() {
        var bigHtml = $('div.large').html();
        var smallHtml = $(this).html();

        $('div.large').html(smallHtml);
        $('div.small').html(bigHtml);

        //custom functions?
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Anyone know why I lose your linebreaks pasting this into Visual Studio?

Comment: This works great BUT you lose any events bound to the divs (like "controlName.change()". Using detach and append preserves the events. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9719297/1359088

Answer (score 1):

```
function swapContent(){
   var tempContent = $("div.large").html();
   $("div.large").empty().html($("div.small").html());
   $("div.small").empty().html(tempContent);   
}

<div class="large">
    <img src="/images/photos/Interior.jpg" alt="The interior" style="[...]" />
    <div class="caption">The interior</div>
</div>
<div class="small" onclick="swapContent()">
    <img src="/images/photos/Bedroom.jpg" alt="Bedroom" style="[A different ...]" />
    <div class="caption">A bedroom</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup a little:

```
<div id="large">

<div id="small">
```

And then in the Javascript you can do:

```
var swap = function(fromId, toId){
    var temp = $(toId).html();
    $(toId).html($(fromId).html());
    $(fromId).html(temp);
}
```

Obviously it can be cleaned up, but you get the idea.

Comment: Changing to id's is not an option, as there are more than one `div.small`